# Why are multiple valid CSS properties shown red in Brackets

Tags: ide, editor, adobe-brackets

Every time I write some of these properties in Brackets:

```
gap:20px;
aspect-ratio:16/9;
backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
scroll-behavior: smooth;
scrollbar-width: thin;
```

They show up in red color, signaling that those lines are invalid, even though they show nicely in every modern browser. Does anybody know why does this happen?